# Laravel 5.2 | can't upload file to database

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to upload profile picture when register into a column named "fotodosen". I already tried this but still doesn't work.

This is my method in DosenController:

```
public function store(CreateDosenRequest $request)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $request->input('name'),
        'username' => $request->input('username'),
        'email' => $request->input('email'),
        'password' => $request->input('password'),
        'admin' => $request->input('admin'),
     ]);

      $dosen = Dosen::create([
        'iddosen' => $request->input('iddosen'),
        'nipy' => $request->input('nipy'),
        'namadosen' => $user->name,
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'alamatdosen' => $request->input('alamatdosen'),
        'notelpdosen' => $request->input('notelpdosen'),
        'tempatlahirdosen' => $request->input('tempatlahirdosen'),
        'tanggallahirdosen' => $request->input('tanggallahirdosen'),
        'agamadosen' => $request->input('agamadosen'),

    ]);

    return redirect('admin/dosen')->with('message', 'Data berhasil ditambahkan!');    

}
```

I already tried this :

```
public function store(CreateDosenRequest $request)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $request->input('name'),
        'username' => $request->input('username'),
        'email' => $request->input('email'),
        'password' => $request->input('password'),
        'admin' => $request->input('admin'),
     ]);

      $dosen = Dosen::create([
        'iddosen' => $request->input('iddosen'),
        'nipy' => $request->input('nipy'),
        'namadosen' => $user->name,
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'alamatdosen' => $request->input('alamatdosen'),
        'notelpdosen' => $request->input('notelpdosen'),
        'tempatlahirdosen' => $request->input('tempatlahirdosen'),
        'tanggallahirdosen' => $request->input('tanggallahirdosen'),
        'agamadosen' => $request->input('agamadosen'),

    ]);

  if($request->hasFile('fotodosen')){
$file = Input::file('fotodosen');
$file = $file->move(public_path().'/uploads/',$file->getOriginalFileName());
$user->fotodosen = $file->getRealPath();
 }
 $user->save();
  return $user;

    return redirect('admin/dosen')->with('message', 'Data berhasil ditambahkan!');    

}
```

but it still doesn't work.

This is my form :

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'admin/dosen', 'files' => true, 'method' => 'post')) }}
                            {!! Form::file('fotodosen', null) !!}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                <i class="fa fa-btn fa-user"></i> Register
                            </button>
                             {!! Form::close() !!}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Possible, 'files' => true works not properly here. Please check if generated form looks like this one: `<form ... enctype='multipart/form-data'>`

Comment: nothing change. still can't input photo

Comment: did you checked generated html code of that form? Is it contains enctype param?

Comment: `<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/infodosenku/public/admin/dosen" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="EkpyvQ93pLYBNGiA1rHuRzeyrYY2yCNjhUtV4aw8">
                                <input name="fotodosen" type="file">

                       
                                 </form>`

Comment: okay, could you please do a `var_dump($request->hasFile('fotodosen'))` somewhere in the code and say me what is value there?